# Image gallery li height not re-adjusting

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am running into an issue with the height of an li.

[Here is a codepen with the issue.](http://codepen.io/tnormington/pen/jPddXq)

```
 <div class="row fp-gallery">
  <ul class="large-block-grid-4 medium-block-grid-4 small-block-grid-2">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/200X200" /></a>
      <div class="description">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Words about the image</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/200X200" /></a>
      <div class="description">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Words about the image</p>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/200X200" /></a>
      <div class="description">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Words about the image</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://placehold.it/200X200" /></a>
      <div class="description">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Words about the image</p>
      </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see here, I have built an unordered list with 4 list item's. Each list item contains a link with an image, and a description div. The description is located inside the list item for positioning reasons, and this places the div underneath the image. Using CSS, I re-positioned the description div on top of the image.

My issue is, even after the description is re-positioned, the list item still holds its shape as if the description were still positioned underneath the image. this causes problems with the hover handler, allowing you to trigger the hover by mousing over the empty space underneath the image.

I gave each list item a red border for better understanding.

I would like each list item to be the same height as it's contained image.

PS. I'm using Foundation's block-grid to build my image gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using position:absolute for the .description

```
.fp-gallery .description {
    position: absolute;
}
```

In addition to this you need to set its parent to position:relative

```
.fp-gallery ul li {
    position: relative;
}
```

Updated codepen is available at the following location
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVqqoB

Comment: Much love, it's funny it was solved by adding 2 attributes >.<

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you want but you can try this.

```
.fp-gallery ul li {
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position:relative;
  padding:0px 0px 100px 0px !important;
}

.fp-gallery .description {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: $darkblue;
  color: $white;
  bottom: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s all ease;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did with jQuery:

Firstly, I modified the document ready function to a window load function (which will wait until the images have loaded, so jQuery can tell the height of the loaded images) -

`$(window).load(function(){`...

Then I added this to the `image.each()` call:

```
$(this).css('height', $(this).find('img').height() + 4);
```

Which sets the list element to the same height as its child image, with an extra 4 pixels to accommodate the border-width for top and bottom.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJvvZY

Also, you can make it a resize event as well as load so it stays that way:

`$(window).on('load resize', function() {`...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNZZmM

I know you already picked an answer, but I was working on it anyway, so why not share?

Comment: I appreciate the response. The beauty in coding is there is never 1 answer.